# iOS simulator only shows app in a quarter of the screen

Tags: ios, screen, simulator

Since 2 days, when starting the app in the emulator it opens the app 1/4 of the screen size. iPhone 6 and tested it with the iPhone 6 Plus as well...
even home is quarter-sized

'Cleaned' the project, 'Reset contents and settings' of the iOS simulator. But still not solved.
[image: simulator screenshot]
[image: Home screen]

Quiting and relaunching the simulator did not work.
As you can see in the bottom screenshot changing the scale does not help.

The problem does not apear in version 'Xcode 7 Beta 4'.

Comment: what is the simulator size? and the view controller size? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: 50%, when changing to other sizes the problem remains :(. Auto layout has always been active, but only for 2 days it seems to be a problem

Comment: I mean specifications is it the iPad simulator or iPhone simulator?

Comment: just quit the simulator and launch it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be solved after I installed the Xcode 7 beta 5 (next to the 6.4)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am quite new in iOS. I had the same problem, this is what I did and resolved

1 - xcode 7.1.1.
2 - In the file Inspector, right hand Pane
3 - In "**Interface Builder Document**", I chose **Xcode 5.1**; the one I used to do programming before El Capitan and new Xcode installed.

Comment: Re-install did not work for me. But the problem was gone when starting to use xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

Use this key it may solve your problem

```
 ⌘+1 for 100%
 ⌘+2 for 75%
 ⌘+3 for 50%
```

Comment: thx, but that only changes the scale, so still the screen is only filled half in both ways :(

Answer (score 0):

I should first point out for others that this is a simulator/Xcode problem not an app problem, as the simulator also displays the issue when you are in the simulator menus (Apple's menus).

Now the actual workaround, which can take several tries:

1) In the simulator "Menu bar" (the "iOS simulator" top bar, next to the Apple symbol to log off the machine - so not XCode's), select the hardware you want to use (e.g. "hardware > iphone 6"), and cross your fingers.

2) Wait for the Apple home screen to appear in the simulator:

- If home is NOT full screen, then switch to another hardware (any can do - you could switch between 6 and 6 plus), wait for the menus to appear and then go back to step 1 (or to be clear: you need to switch back and forth between the hardware you want and another random hardware until you have the simulator full screen)
- If home is full screen then go to step 3, you're fine for now and can do your testing (pressing "test" will use the current full screen simulator)

3) Make sure XCode and the simulator are testing/running the same "iPhone" version (otherwise XCode will invalidate all your efforts by restarting a new simulator).
So if you have managed to make an "iPhone 6 plus" simulator full screen, make sure in XCode "iPhone 6 plus" is selected at the top near the "run project" play button so that XCode does NOT restart the simulator for you.

I would say it takes me between 30 seconds to 2-3 minute to get a working simulator this way.
If you don't switch sizes often and can leave your simulator opened, it is actually not that bad.

(PS: tried and tested at least 10 times now)

Comment: did not help for me, alas :(

Comment: It's back now for me! :( I will take a look see if I can remember how I fixed it yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, tried it for at least 15 times with no success.
The issue does not happen in Xcode Beta so I guess I will test it there

Comment: I gues something must have gone wrong when using my Project in both Xcode versions