# How to create screenshots for itunes from my ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, publish

I try to create screenshots from my app for all the screensizes in itunes:
4.7, 5.5, 4, 3.5, Ipad inches. 
I have only an Ipad device, for which I can create screenshots without problems.
I can also use the IOS-Simulator for creating screenshots, but they are not usable. See following screenshot from my 5s simulator:

[image]

There is only one quarter of the screen showed in the screenshot and the quality is very bad.
How do you do this ?

Comment: Normally I use photoshop to resize the image

Comment: I've used the Simulator to create screenshots with no problem. It shouldn't make a difference but do you have the device scaling set to 100%?

Comment: Do you actually use the menu option in the simulator menu to invoke the screen shot?

Comment: @Gilesey. Yes I do. And then I do not get the screenshot of the device, but the screenshot of the mac-window. The macwindow is 4 times bigger then the screen.

Comment: Your issue is unclear. When you run your app in an iPhone simulator, does your app appear correctly? Is it only the screenshot that is bad? How are you taking the screenshot?

Comment: Only the screen is bad. Its not my app, that makes the issue. Its the simulator, which doesn't show the screen in "fullscreen mode". It shows the screen in the upper left as shown in the screenshot in this question. When I create the screenshot from the simulator from the menu, 3/4 of the picture is just black. I already restarted everything, but still there is the problem. I also tested through all scaling modes.

Comment: I just found a similar issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611240/ios-simulator-only-shows-app-in-a-quarter-of-the-screen

Comment: I solved the problem by just upgrading to Xcode7.1. No it works well. Thanks for helping to you all. Shall I close this question ?